# Getting error while create a block with wordpress/create-block package

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I tried to create a new block with [@wordpress/create-block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-create-block/) package and it resulted into the following error:

```
npm init @wordpress/block todo-list

npx: installed 205 in 10.545s
/Users/macname/.npm/_npx/89564/lib/node_modules/@wordpress/create-block/lib/scaffold.js:4
const { writeFile } = require( 'fs' ).promises;
    ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property `writeFile` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alokjain/.npm/_npx/89564/lib/node_modules/@wordpress/create-block/lib/scaffold.js:4:38)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alokjain/.npm/_npx/89564/lib/node_modules/@wordpress/create-block/lib/index.js:15:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
```

Is there any particular node version or another package needed to run this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're using node 10+, you should be able to run this.

First, run `npm cache clean --force` to avoid any cache issues.

The create-block package is very actively developed - [the latest version was released just 24 hours](http://%20https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/releases/tag/%40wordpress%2Fcreate-block%400.16.0) before your post so also make sure you're using the latest version.

You can find out the version that you're running by issuing `npm init @wordpress/block -V`

If that still fails, [create an issue on github](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues).